# How to make a colored markers legend from scratch

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, legend, markers

In Matplotlib, I'm trying to make a legend with colored "markers" like this one :

[image: Markers legend]

this one has been made using the `scatter` function, but is not adapted to my plot. I'd like to produce a legend "from scratch", without associated data.
The color is important, and therefore should be an attribute of each marker.

I've tried

```
import matplotlib.markers as mmark
list_mak = [mmark.MarkerStyle('.'),mmark.MarkerStyle(','),mmark.MarkerStyle('o')]
list_lab = ['Marker 1','Marker 2','Marker 3']

plt.legend(list_mak,list_lab)
```

But :

1. The `MarkerStyle` class doesn't support color information
2. I get the warning :

   UserWarning: Legend does not support <matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle object at 0x7fca640c44d0> instances.
   A proxy artist may be used instead.

But how can I define a proxy artist based on a marker ?

Comment: Have you read the legend guide? https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists

Comment: Yes of course but there is no explicit references for a "markers" legend

Comment: There is an example there that shows how to add a blue star using a `line2D` object. There's no reason why you can't do the same (with just a marker, no line) for each of your markers.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Following the example given in the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists), you can use a [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html?highlight=line2d) object instead of a `marker` object.

The only difference to the example given in the guide is you want to set `linestyle='None'`

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

blue_star = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue', marker='*', linestyle='None',
                          markersize=10, label='Blue stars')
red_square = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='red', marker='s', linestyle='None',
                          markersize=10, label='Red squares')
purple_triangle = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='purple', marker='^', linestyle='None',
                          markersize=10, label='Purple triangles')

plt.legend(handles=[blue_star, red_square, purple_triangle])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good trick, but using of something called "Line2D" is a bit misleading

Comment: in matplotlib, "markers" are just things that are used in the `plt.plot` or `plt.scatter` functions. `plt.plot` creates `Line2D` objects, `plt.scatter` creates `PathCollection` objects. If you want markers in your legend, you essentially have to use one of those two objects. I find `Line2D` the easier to work with for this case. It's not a "trick", just one way to do the job you are asking.

Comment: indeed its a nice and helpful way to do the job!

Answer (score 5):

You could subclass the `HandlerBase` to create a handler from a tuple of `(color, marker)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase

list_color  = ["c", "gold", "crimson"]
list_mak    = ["d","s","o"]
list_lab    = ['Marker 1','Marker 2','Marker 3']

ax = plt.gca()

class MarkerHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, tup,xdescent, ydescent,
                        width, height, fontsize,trans):
        return [plt.Line2D([width/2], [height/2.],ls="",
                       marker=tup[1],color=tup[0], transform=trans)]


ax.legend(list(zip(list_color,list_mak)), list_lab, 
          handler_map={tuple:MarkerHandler()}) 

plt.show()
```

[image]