# Plotting arrow in front of legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am totally new to Python and I am trying to make a plot for my bachelor thesis. This plot includes arrows that have to appear in the legend. I saw some questions here on Stackoverflow how to add arrows to legends but couldn't follow them. So I made a line with zero linewidth as a placeholder and wanted to generate an arrow in front of the legend. Unfortunatly, I am not able to put the arrow in front of the legend. You can see my arrow in the second to last code line. I tried to move it in front with "zorder" but it doesn't work. It is only bad visible through the transparent legend, as you can see in the linked graphic. I am happy for any help to get this arrow in the legend. Thank you in advance!

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio

plt.style.use('ggplot')

mat=sio.loadmat('MatlabDaten/absolut.mat')
x=mat['x']
x=x[0]
xaufp=mat['xaufp']
xaufp=xaufp[0]
y=mat['y']
y=y[0]
yaufp=mat['yaufp']
yaufp=yaufp[0]
pfeillaenge=mat['pfeillaenge']
pfeillaenge=pfeillaenge[0]
pfeilpos=mat['pfeilpos']

ppfad=plt.plot(x,y,'C0',label='Geplanter Pfad')
paufp=plt.plot(xaufp,yaufp,'C0o',label='Aufpunkte')
plt.plot(0,0,lw=0,label='Lokale Orientierung')
for count in pfeilpos:
    ppfeil=plt.arrow(count[0],count[1],pfeillaenge[0],pfeillaenge[1], fc='C1', ec='C1', lw = 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.06, overhang = 0.3, length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False, label='Lokale Orientierung')
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
plt.xlabel('$x$-Koordinate')
plt.ylabel('$y$-Koordinate')
plt.title('Absolute Orientierung')
plt.legend(handles=[ppfad,paufp,ppfeil],loc='lower left')
pfeil=plt.arrow(0.15,-1.32,0.3,0, fc='C1', ec='C1', lw = 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.06, overhang = 0.3, length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False, label='Lokale Orientierung')
pfeil.set_zorder(+5)
```

Resulting Plot:
[image: Resulting Plot]

Comment: Very interesting question.  Does this post help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47392973/6067379 it describes creating custom legend markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to deal with this problem is to create a custom [legend handler](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/legend_handler_api.html#module-matplotlib.legend_handler). The following is based on [matplotlib's legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerPatch
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

class HandlerArrow(HandlerPatch):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        p = mpatches.FancyArrow(0, 0.5*height, width, 0, length_includes_head=True, head_width=0.75*height )
        self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
        p.set_transform(trans)
        return [p]


plt.style.use('ggplot')

#mat=sio.loadmat('MatlabDaten/absolut.mat')
#x=mat['x']
#x=x[0]
#xaufp=mat['xaufp']
#xaufp=xaufp[0]
#y=mat['y']
#y=y[0]
#yaufp=mat['yaufp']
#yaufp=yaufp[0]
#pfeillaenge=mat['pfeillaenge']
#pfeillaenge=pfeillaenge[0]
#pfeilpos=mat['pfeilpos']
x = [1,4]
y = [-1,1]
xaufp = [1,4]
yaufp = [-1,1]
pfeilpos = [[1,-1],[4,1]]
pfeillaenge = [0,0.25]

fig = plt.figure()
ppfad=plt.plot(x,y,'C0',label='Geplanter Pfad')
paufp=plt.plot(xaufp,yaufp,'C0o',label='Aufpunkte')
for count in pfeilpos:
    ppfeil=plt.arrow(count[0],count[1],pfeillaenge[0],pfeillaenge[1], fc='C1', ec='C1', lw = 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.06, overhang = 0.3, length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False, label='Lokale Orientierung')
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
plt.xlabel('$x$-Koordinate')
plt.ylabel('$y$-Koordinate')
plt.title('Absolute Orientierung')

h,l = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
h.append(ppfeil)
l.append('Lokale Orientierung')
plt.legend(h,l, handler_map={mpatches.FancyArrow : HandlerArrow()})
```

[image]

Note that this is often overkill, and you can also use the ability of `scatter` to use [custom markers](https://www.sascha-frank.com/Arrow/latex-arrows.html) to trick matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio

plt.style.use('ggplot')

#mat=sio.loadmat('MatlabDaten/absolut.mat')
#x=mat['x']
#x=x[0]
#xaufp=mat['xaufp']
#xaufp=xaufp[0]
#y=mat['y']
#y=y[0]
#yaufp=mat['yaufp']
#yaufp=yaufp[0]
#pfeillaenge=mat['pfeillaenge']
#pfeillaenge=pfeillaenge[0]
#pfeilpos=mat['pfeilpos']
x = [1,4]
y = [-1,1]
xaufp = [1,4]
yaufp = [-1,1]
pfeilpos = [[1,-1],[4,1]]
pfeillaenge = [0,0.25]

fig = plt.figure()
ppfad=plt.plot(x,y,'C0',label='Geplanter Pfad')
paufp=plt.plot(xaufp,yaufp,'C0o',label='Aufpunkte')
for count in pfeilpos:
    ppfeil=plt.arrow(count[0],count[1],pfeillaenge[0],pfeillaenge[1], fc='C1', ec='C1', lw = 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.06, overhang = 0.3, length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False, label='Lokale Orientierung')
plt.scatter([],[],marker=r'$\rightarrow$', label='Lokale Orientierung', color='C1', s=100) # dummy scatter to add an item to the legend
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
plt.xlabel('$x$-Koordinate')
plt.ylabel('$y$-Koordinate')
plt.title('Absolute Orientierung')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, your code gets me an error:

```TypeError: get_legend_handles_labels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'```

I wrote "self" into the brackets, but this even gets more errors...

Comment: How did you define your "ax."? Because I always used "plt.plot" and I guess this causes the error

Comment: I don't know what to say... It works perfectly! I've gone for your "overkill" solution since I think if I learn this, I can alsways go back to the simpler solution, but also the overkill solution works... just perfectly! Thank you so much!!!