# pyplot: Make legend in text box environment

Tags: matplotlib

This may be my naive thought, but it appears to me that legend is just text with some lines in front.
I wonder if it is possible to use text environment to draw legends directly without using the legend environment.

The motivation is that, say I have Figure A with legend, then I plot Figure B with some relevant quantities to Figure A but they have their own legends. However, I would also like to show the legend of Figure A in Figure B as an annotation for example.

Two ways that I can think of to achieve the above effect are:

1. I use subplot to put Figure A and B together;
2. I simply get a screenshot of the Figure A legend and paste it on Figure B.

But sometimes it is very inconvenient to use method 1, and method 2 is not pythonic.

Thanks in advance for any good ideas!

Comment: A possible solution is to make Figure A, save it, and then clear the Axes while conserving the legend, and then make Figure B on this basis. It would have been simpler if an Artist could have been shared between Figures, but that is not possible.

Comment: @Patol75 Thanks for the comment! I am wondering if it is possible to draw a legend in Figure B? Say the legend of Figure A is a red solid line with the name Line A. Then in Figure B I just use the text environment and draw a red solid line within the box and write Line A after that. Do you happen to know if this is doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two different legends by specifying one for the Axes object and one for the Figure object, as below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1, 2, 3]
ax.plot(x, x, color='xkcd:avocado', linestyle='dashed', label='Test')
figAmarkers, = ax.plot(x, x, color='xkcd:cerulean', linestyle='none',
                       marker='*', markersize=10)
ax.legend(title='Figure B Legend')
figAmarkers.set_label('Blue stars')
fig.legend(handles=[figAmarkers], loc='lower right',
           bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, bbox_to_anchor=[1, 0],
           title='Figure A Legend')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47392973/10640534) if you only need the legend, without the associated Artists on the plot.